# Emacs on Windows 7 very slow when computer is outside company network

Tags: microsoft-windows, performance, networking

I'm using GNU Emacs 24.3 on Windows 7 and normally I don't have any problems with speed/responsiveness.

I'm launching Emacs with `runemacs.exe`

However, when I am travelling and try to connect to my company network via VPN (or just working offline without a connection to the company network), Emacs often becomes incredibly slow — it might take many minutes to open a buffer and it just does not respond to keyboard commands.

(I'm still highly interested in a solution)
All relevant text and configuration files are saved in my user directory `C:\Users\myusername.domainname\Documents` which is located on the local hard disk (so should not need accessing remote servers), but I wonder if Windows 7 might try to sync those files with a server

I'm also using the "offline files" feature for other directories and I wonder if this could have an effect on my problem.

The problem occurs not only when VPN is used, but also when the computer is just offline and not connected to the company network.

Comment: Since "The problem occurs not only when VPN is used, but also when the computer is just offline and not connected to the company network" it's not clear that the VPN has anything to do with the problem.

Comment: How about using the most recent public release of Emacs instead of 24.3?  Is there a reason to try and troubleshoot an older version of Emacs when a newer stable release is readily available?

Comment: @lawlist: thanks, I think I'm currently using Emacs 24.5, I'll check that tomorrow when I'm back at the computer. Anyway, shouldn't it be possible in every stable Emacs release to work in any network setting without problems?

Comment: check your dns settings and make sure you're using a local/speedy dns server

Comment: Why would Emacs be making DNS requests? Why would slowness be due to DNS requests rather than some other kind of network access?

Comment: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gnu-emacs/2012-10/msg00230.html offers some hints and `(setq w32-get-true-file-attributes nil)` might help.

Answer (score 4):

The reason of this problem can be using of the `recentf` mode. You need to disable cleaning up unavailable files using following command in your ~/.emacs (or ~/.emacs.d/init.el if you are using it):

```
(setq recentf-auto-cleanup 'never)
```

Comment: thanks a lot - that looks promising, but I do not use `recentf` mode and could not find such an option in my .emacs or init.el

Comment: I'm having the same problem as OP, and this did nothing to help me.

Comment: I can't think of any reason whatsoever recentf would have any impact. It's simply a list of recent files. They are not restored or checked,

Comment: A very large recentf file can indeed introduce intermittent latency, but this does not seem to be the problem as described by OP.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, and [it seems like it is being caused by the windows netlogon service](http://www.hydrus.org.uk/journal/emacs-netlogon.html). The simplest solution is to turn it off when outside your company network, by running the following command in the command line:

```
net stop netlogon
```

When you are back on the company network, start it again using

```
net start netlogon
```

Comment: net stop netlogon This solved my issue with emacs 27.1 under Cygwin with VPN connection to employer.

Answer (score 2):

Quite a few possible reasons, two off the top of my head (had these troubles in the past.)

1. You may have a remote folder mapped in Windows, and when off the local network it may slow you down a lot (getting off the VPN doesn't quite help, actually it may make matters worse since Windows will keep trying to reach it stopped only by timeouts.) More recent versions of Windows seem to deal a bit better with it, but still. Try to run `net use * /delete` in a command prompt and see if it helps.
2. Check if you are using `tramp` (I doubt it since you are on Windows, but I am using Windows too along with Linux and I do use `tramp` so it's not totally out of question.) If so, try to run `tramp-cleanup-all-connections` when off the network.

If all this or anything else people suggest here doesn't help you may need to run deeper troubleshooting. The best tool I've found for it is Sysinternals' Process Monitor (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645). It's a complex beast to deal with, and it requires at least basic understanding of Windows operating system, but it is capable of taking guesswork totally out of the process and zeroing down on the offender.

Comment: net use * showed me nothing. But it turned out my current directory did contain a symbolic link to a remote directory. Only procmon got me the clue I needed to figure it out, as this answer suggested.