# Disk interaction occasionally extremely slow

Tags: microsoft-windows, files

I'm using `GNU Emacs 24.5.1 (i686-pc-mingw32) of 2015-04-11 on LEG570` on Windows 7. Somedays (yes, weirdly, it seems to be only some days), Emacs takes a very long time (a few seconds) when reading or writing to disk. This happens most notably when using `ido-find-file` or `save-buffer`. It happens in fundamental mode, and when i run `emacs -q`, so I don't think it is related to my setup.

It doesn't seem to happen in other text-editors, but it might just be that other text-editors does save asynchronously, while emacs is famously single-threaded, and so would block everytime. I suspect that the issue might come from some of the spyware that my employer installs on our computers, but I'm at a loss on how to debug. What could the source of this error be?

I've tried the profiler to find the source of the slowness. Here is the output for one slow save:

```
- ...                                                               5  83%
   Automatic GC                                                     5  83%
- command-execute                                                   1  16%
 - call-interactively                                               1  16%
  - profiled-save-buffer                                            1  16%
   - let                                                            1  16%
    - save-buffer                                                   1  16%
     - basic-save-buffer                                            1  16%
      - basic-save-buffer-1                                         1  16%
         basic-save-buffer-2                                        1  16%
```

Of course, this is very weird. The actual save took 13.863000 seconds, the sampling interval is 1000000. If I understand the profiler correctly I should have more than 1000 samples, but here I only got one. Here is the code I use for profiling:

```
(defun profiled-save-buffer ()
    ""
  (interactive)
  (profiler-start 'cpu)
  (measure-time
   (save-buffer)
  (profiler-report)
  (profiler-stop))
  (select-window (previous-window)))
```

Comment: run `profiler` and post the report. Maybe people can find which command is consuming more time and space.

Comment: Do you use magit? Sometimes while Emacs seems to hang and I interrupt it with C-g I get an error message related to some magit hook.

Comment: During these freezes, not even ctrl-g works

Comment: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gnu-emacs/2012-10/msg00230.html offers some hints and `(setq w32-get-true-file-attributes nil)` might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused by the windows netlogon service. This questions seems to be a duplicate of [this one](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3669/emacs-on-windows-7-very-slow-when-computer-is-outside-company-network/30212#3021) and too which I've answered with the solution I found [here](http://www.hydrus.org.uk/journal/emacs-netlogon.html).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and the solution referred by arvidj worked for me.

If you don't bother to know the details, the short answer is to stop Netlogon by command (you need to run the command prompt as administrator)

`net stop netlogon`

You need to do it after each time of restarting your computer.

You may run "services.msc," from which you can disable the Netlogon service.

[image]